# Python method call syntax shorthand

Tags: python, methods, syntax, self

Is there a reason we call methods in python like `object.method` instead of `Class.method(object)`?

Maybe it isn't a strange choice, but personally it made understanding the `self` parameter much easier when I was shown the second way of calling a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcoding the class name basically prevents you from using polymorphism. This is general OOP, not particularly a Python feature.

Your calling code should not need to know, nor care, which exact class `object` is.

This is immediately a problem for code where `object` can be a member of either `Baseclass` or `Derivedclass`, but much more complex inheritance and method overriding scenarios are possible, and sometimes necessary.